# xbuild compiles without errors but dont have .exe files?

Tags: visual-studio, mono, xbuild

Only For educational purposes.

Basically I am trying to compile Juicy Potato exploit. I found a visual studio project from github and Now I am trying to compile it using mono `xbuild`, Although it compiles without any errors but I can't find the `binary or .exe` files.

see below:

```
>>>> xbuild tool is deprecated and will be removed in future updates, use msbuild instead <<<<

XBuild Engine Version 14.0
Mono, Version 5.18.0.240
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors

Build started 2019-10-10 3:30:02 PM.
__________________________________________________
/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato/JuicyPotato.sln:  warning : Ignoring vcproj 'JuicyPotato'.
/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato/JuicyPotato.sln:  warning : Failed to find project 4164003e-ba47-4a95-8586-d5aac399c050
/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato/JuicyPotato.sln:  warning : Don't know how to handle GlobalSection ExtensibilityGlobals, Ignoring.
Project "/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato/JuicyPotato.sln"     (default target(s)):
    Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
            Building solution configuration "Debug|x64".
Done building project "/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-    potato/JuicyPotato/JuicyPotato.sln".

Build succeeded.

Warnings:

/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato/JuicyPotato.sln:  warning : Ignoring vcproj 'JuicyPotato'.
/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato/JuicyPotato.sln:  warning : Failed to find project 4164003e-ba47-4a95-8586-d5aac399c050
/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato/JuicyPotato.sln:  warning : Don't     know how to handle GlobalSection ExtensibilityGlobals, Ignoring.

     3 Warning(s)
     0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.1375220
root@kali:/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato# ls
JuicyPotato  JuicyPotato.sdf  JuicyPotato.sln
root@kali:/home/HTB/Json/10.10.10.158/nmap/juicy_potato/juicy-potato/JuicyPotato# uname -a
Linux kali 4.19.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.20-1kali1 (2019-02-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

my **.vcxproj**

````
    <Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{4164003E-BA47-4A95-8586-D5AAC399C050}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>JuicyPotato</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>8.1</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <ProjectName>JuicyPotato</ProjectName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>```

Bottom:


      ```<PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;MSFROTTENPOTATO_EXPORTS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;% (PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
     </ClCompile>
     <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalDependencies>secur32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
     </Link>
     <BuildLog>
      <Path>$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\$(MSBuildProjectName).log</Path>
    </BuildLog>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <Text Include="ReadMe.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
     <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="BlockingQueue.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="IStorageTrigger.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="LocalNegotiator.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="MSFRottenPotato.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="targetver.h" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="dllmain.cpp">
      <CompileAsManaged Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">false</CompileAsManaged>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <CompileAsManaged Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">false</CompileAsManaged>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <CompileAsManaged Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">false</CompileAsManaged>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <CompileAsManaged Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">false</CompileAsManaged>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
      </PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="IStorageTrigger.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="LocalNegotiator.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="JuicyPotato.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
   </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
   <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
   </ImportGroup>
    </Project>```

Architecture:

    Linux kali 4.19.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.20-1kali1 (2019-02-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
````

Comment: When it says so clear "xbuild tool is deprecated and will be removed in future updates, use msbuild instead" you should follow it, even for educational purposes.

Comment: I found the binary files on the web. Totally do not recommend it as it could be other potential stuff and backdoors, but sometimes in life......

Comment: BTW, you are trying to compile a VC++ project, which is in general Windows only. There is no VC++ for Linux.